# Pentaho variables at JVM level

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

Using set variables step in pentaho, I have defined a variable and the scope is set to "valid in the Java virtual machine",  but it is not replacing in one of the sql's used in the table input step.

Table input step is checked with option "replace variables in script". But the same variable when I placed in kettle.properties file, it is working. Pentaho job available in the repository and running from Linux box

Could anyone please share your thoughts?

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of your jobs / transformations or the files themselves?

Answer (score 2):

You can-not set the parameter and use it in the same transformation, because it executes all the steps parallelly.
Logic-wise correct approach is first set the variable and get the variable in next transformation and further use or replace in respected steps.

Answer (score 0):

As Working Hard.. says, you can not use a parameter in the same transformation, you have to use another transformation after setting the variables.